# target multiple text fields one at a time, not all at once without using ID's

Tags: jquery, ajax

I haven't done it yet, but I plan to generate text fields with php based on the user input. So, if they type 3, then they should get 3 text fields to fill in etc.

Instead of trying to give each text field an ID (I would have to apply code to number the text field and increment based on the number they chose) can I just select a class or input? I have tried to do this but with the ajax search, results come up in ALL text fields instead of just the one they are typing in.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $(".loader").show();
        var input = $(this).val();
        if (input.length >3){
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'insert-ajax.php',
                  data: {name:input},
                  success: function(data){

                      if(!data.error) {
                      $(".result").html(data);
                      $(".loader").hide();
                      }
                  }

              });
            } 

                if (input.length <1) {
                    $(".loader").hide();
                    $(".result").html("");
                }
        });

        $(".result").on( "click", "li", function() {
                console.log($(this).text());
            $("input").val($(this).text());

            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery objects, you get a great set of traversal functions you could use here. As I understand, in each of your `.results` divs, you have an unordered list, and you want to be able to click on an `li` in that list and have the nearest text field fill a value. Assuming I'm right, you could use the `.closest()` function to get the ancestor `.results` `div` for that `li` and then get the nearest input field using the `.siblings()` function. So something like:

```
$(".result").on( "click", "li", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).closest(".result").siblings("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

Kind of messy, but this will work. That said, I'm not sure why you're doing this inside a keyup handler. It can cause multiple on click handlers to be added for the `li` tags.

Comment: Thanks Ananth, I am doing with keyup because when the user starts typing I want the loader to start showing. That is the main reason I used keyup. I will try your code as soon as I am back in front of my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the

```
$('input').val($this().text);
```

in your keyup function like

```
$(this).text(data);
```

instead of

```
$('.result').html(data);
```